# How is it possible to expand a DATE column in R?

Tags: r, date, expand

I have a data frame with several columns, in the first the DATE, in the others the daily temperature of different sites

```
     DATE         SITE1         SITE2                  
1    2017-01-01  0.101694912   0.15413890   
2    2017-01-02 -0.118305088  -0.06586110    
3    2017-01-03 -0.938305088  -0.88586110   
4    2017-01-04  1.501694912   1.55413890   
5    2017-01-05 -1.238305088  -1.18586110 
....
```

How can I expand the data frame adding a new DATE-HOUR column (by assigning the same temperature value to all the hour of the same day in the different sites)?

```
    DATE           DATE-HOUR             SITE1         SITE2                    
1    2017-01-01   2017-01-01-1:00:00    0.101694912   0.15413890  
2    2017-01-01   2017-01-01-2:00:00    0.101694912   0.15413890    
3    2017-01-01   2017-01-01-3:00:00    0.101694912   0.15413890   
.... 

25   2017-01-02   2017-01-01:00:00     -0.118305088  -0.06586110   
26   2017-01-02   2017-01-02:00:00     -0.118305088  -0.06586110   
27   2017-01-02   2017-01-03:00:00     -0.118305088  -0.06586110    
..
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat long-winded but effective and all done within base R:

```
n <- nrow(df)
df <- df[rep(seq(n), each = 24),]
df$DATETIME <- as.POSIXct(df$DATE) + rep(0:23 * 3600, n)
df <- df[c(1, 4, 2, 3)]
df
#>            DATE            DATETIME      SITE1      SITE2
#> 1    2017-01-01 2017-01-01 00:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> 1.1  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 01:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> 1.2  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 02:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> 1.3  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 03:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> 1.4  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 04:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> 1.5  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 05:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> 1.6  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 06:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> 1.7  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 07:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> 1.8  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 08:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> 1.9  2017-01-01 2017-01-01 09:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> 1.10 2017-01-01 2017-01-01 10:00:00  0.1016949  0.1541389
#> ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Allan, 
and if I want to add a column DATE_MINUTE, how does it work? It's better to start from the DATE or from the DATETIME? 
I tried with this string but there is a mistake that I don't understand..

from the data frame with the DATETIME

```
n <- nrow(df)
df <- df[rep(seq(n), each = 60),]
df$DATE_MINUTE <- as.POSIXct(df$DATETIME) + rep(0:59 * 60, n)
```